# Postgresql - Transaction isolation

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, psql

Hi I am new to PostgreSQL transaction isolation level, I wanted to learn more on different isolation level in PostgreSQL. I have 2 windows here. Each running PSQL shell, to emulate 2 clients, to my PostgreSQL server in my local machine.

I tried to insert into the table with non transaction query in `test` table with one client and set up a read committed isolation based transaction in other client.

I find it weird how can `read committed isolation level` see changes made from the other client. Isn't the read committed meant to see a snapshot of the changes in the beginning of `begin transaction` state.

[image: Pictorial Explanation of the problem]

In the left,

> SELECT statement being run inside of a transaction.

In the right,

> INSERT statement being run in non transaction environment

Can you explain me on how is this meant to happen ?

Comment: It is behaving as expected. 'Repeatable read' and 'read committed' are different levels.

Comment: 1) `psql` has autocommit on by default so each insert is being commited immediately. 2) From here [Read Committed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED): "Also note that two successive SELECT commands can see different data, even though they are within a single transaction, if other transactions commit changes after the first SELECT starts and before the second SELECT starts.

Comment: What you are looking for is [Repeatable Read](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ): "Thus, successive SELECT commands within a single transaction see the same data, i.e., they do not see changes made by other transactions that committed after their own transaction started."